# Постинг картинок Wall.post Вконтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Написал обработчик на PHP, который создает посты в группе. Но стал вопрос с тем, как постить картинку? Пытался добавить ссылкой в `attachments`, но выводит ссылку на картинку, а не добавляет саму картинку(которая находится по этой ссылке). Как это можно исправить?

```html
if( isset( $_POST['send'] ) ){
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$minute = $_POST['minute'];
$photo = $_POST['link']; //тут хранится ссылка на картинку

$senddate = $year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$hour.":".$minute.":00";

$date = strtotime($senddate);


$url  = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-137337424&attachments='.$photo.'&publish_date='.$date.'&v=5.63&access_token=мойтокен';

echo '<iframe src="'.$url.'" width="400px" height="50px"></iframe>';
echo "Выполнено";
```

Comment: Читайте документацию

Comment: @andreymal в документации нет описания случаев добавления картинки ссылкой. Или я просто чего-то пока полностью не понимаю в тонкостях написанной документации

Comment: Значит такой случай недоступен) Заливайте картинки так, как описано в документации и в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед тем, как отправлять пост на стену, необходимо отдельно загрузить публикуемое изображение и сохранить его.

Получаем адрес загрузки с помощью запроса на адрес:
`https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?access_token={your_access_token}&group_id={your_wall_id}`
В результате должен придти ответ с параметром `upload_url` - адрес загрузки фото.

Загружаем и сохраняем фото на сервере Вконтакте:

Отправляем файл по указанному адресу. Можно сделать так: `curl -X POST -F 'photo=@/var/www/myphoto.jpg' '{upload_url}'` или с помощью модуля `CURL` для `php`.
При успешной загрузке придет ответ с параметрами(`server, hash, photo`), которые необходимо передать в следующем запросе для сохранения фото:
`https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto?access_token={your_access_token}&group_id={your_wall_id}&server={server}&photo={photo}&hash={hash}`

Получаем ответ с параметром `id` - ID загруженного изображения.
Формируем значение параметра фото в поле `attachments = photo{your_wall_id}_{photo_id}`, где `photo_id` - `id` загруженного изображения на предыдущем этапе.

копипаст с http://blog.yamaker.ru/6-polnocennyy-avtoposting-v-gruppu-vkontakte-s-pomoschyu-api.html